# Why is iTunes photo sync showing separate event for each photo?

Tags: itunes, data-synchronization, photos.app

I am syncing photos through iTunes to my iphone but I am seeing 40 events with the same date show in the Events selector. The same photos are included within a single event in iPhoto. How can i get iTunes to see these events as one?

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem with iphoto latest version 9.4.2. At genius bar nobody know a solution. Genius talked to Cupertino, they know about the problem, we have to wait for an update for iphoto software.  I tried using "iphoto library manager" software (not apple) to recover the iphoto library. Apparently problem was solved in itunes, but iphoto became very slow and i came back to normal iphoto library.
In itunes events have a date as a name and each contains few pics, some of them have been deleted from the iphoto library but still in those strangfe events, maybe as a miniature.
Somebody can help?
Deleting ipod photo cache non solution, unfortunately.